# Calculating $AB$

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

Here is my diagram

[image]

I want to calculate $AB$ and don't have any idea about where to start. Might I get any help for this question?

Regards!

Comment: What trigonometric functions do you know?

Comment: @rogerl What do you mean, sir? If someone can show it, I'd get it easily.

Comment: Do you know about functions line $\sin(x)$, $\cos(x)$ or $\tan(x)$? Do you know about how they relate to (right) triangles?

Comment: If I tell you that $sinC=\frac{AB}{AC}$, can you then work it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this right triangle, by definition$$sin37^o=\frac{AB}{AC}$$So$$AB=ACsin 37^o$$Look up $sin 37^o$, and then take the product $ACsin 37^o$.  When $BC$ rather than $AC$ is given along with $\angle C$, you use $tanC$ to find $AB$, which is a good way to compute the height of things you'd rather not--or can't--measure by climbing them.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** : First use the fact that the angles of a triangle always add up to 180º (you know two angles already).

Once you know all the angles, use the Law of Sines:

$$\dfrac{a}{sin \  A}=\dfrac{b}{sin \  B} = \dfrac{c}{sin \  C}$$